# How to Execute Subversion Post-Commit Trigger Without New Changeset?

Tags: svn

I'm trying to troubleshoot a post-commit hook script issue.  I need to be able to try different solutions and see if they fix the problem by having Subversion run through its post-commit trigger -- this is critical because the problem lies with the particular user account running the post-commit script and its environment.  (our setup is SVN/Apache, where Apache is running as LocalSystem on Server 2003)

Anyway, filling up the repository with bogus "test only" changesets is sub-optimal.  Is there a better way to tell Subversion to pretend that a real changeset has been committed and to run through the post-commit script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things I might try:

- Move your script to start-commit and intentionally return a non-zero value so the commit doesn't happen.  Depending on what you're trying to work out, this should replicate the environment close enough to debug.
- Execute the script directly within a shell on the server.

Answer (score 1):

When I have this problem, I set up a separate repository to test all my VCS magic. Then when it works, I copy the config over to my production projects.

For Subversion, here are the instructions on how to set up a new repository:

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch05s02.html

This way I don't have to pollute my real repository with fake commits, and I don't bug my fellow developers by breaking their real commits.

Answer (score 0):

Darryl solution to move the script to the start-commit seems fine.

To execute the script directly should be even easier using the "run as" option from the context-menu. Or even running "cmd" as the LocalSystem user and then executing the script...